# installing intel opencl sdk but cannot find platform at clGetPlatformIDs

Tags: installation, opencl, intel

I want to install intel opencl sdk. And surely I did everything written in intel opencl installation guide in intel's website.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-xe-2013-release-notes#_Installation_Notes

I did everything written in there but it doesn't work.

Specifically, I can compile the source but it cannot find the platform at clGetPlatformIDs function. error code is -1001 and there's no -1001 error code at cl.h file. If I uninstall, then I cannot compile at all naturally. It means there's error message at compile time that it cannot find lots of functions and defined values. After I install the opencl sdk then there's no message and compile properly. I think it means that install is done properly. But at runtime, it cannot find platform. What's the problem? I've been struggling about one week. Please help me..

---add---

I forgot to let you know my OS.. and so on;; 
My OS is Red Hat Enterprise 6.3 (Santiago).
My CPU is Intel Xeon CPU E5-2690.
The code I tried have no problem at other machines and platforms.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more details of your system? Especially your OS... sounds like a driver problem

Comment: Thanks kronos but in my opinion, if it were a driver problem, the problem or error would be occured at clGetDeviceIDs. But It cannot find a platform at all.

Comment: My suggestion is that you are not linking properly. When you call getplatform you are calling elsewhere, and returns some crap.

Comment: I eventually resolve the problem. It was the environment value problem. Intel web site installation guide guide me to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH like this "$export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${OCL_INSTALL_DIR}\bin:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" but \bin doesn't work and \lib64 does. Thanks for lots of your helping